# Getting a weird error trying to verify a smart contract through hardhat

Tags: solidity, verify, hardhat

I am trying to verify on hardhat this nft-tutorial by chainlink https://blog.chain.link/build-deploy-and-sell-your-own-dynamic-nft/ but am unable to. What might be the problem? is it my syntax? Or just an issue with the libraries? (The contract address on Rinkeby is `0xA4630A1f2DaC2474d7397E7e8F3A41Bd574C1f9d`). Addresses for the other constructor arguments are

```
RINKEBY_VRF_COORDINATOR = "0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B"
RINKEBY_LINKTOKEN = "0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709"
RINKEBY_KEYHASH =   "0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311"
```

If you want to give it a shot, here is the github repo with my contract https://github.com/VictorOmbui/chainlink-nft. You can download and try to verify

Here is what I get from the console
[image]

Comment: Hi! The usual recommendation is to post code instead of links - it makes it easier for people to answer questions. Could you post a code block with the part of the deploy script that deploys the contract? (You can make code blocks with three backtics ``` before and after the code.) It would also be nice if you could swap out the console screenshot for text. Cheers!

Comment: Could you please make this a minimum reproduce-able code? Your issue is realated to the truffle-verify plugin. Could you please post your truffle command, and your error in text, and not a picture?

Comment: Shared updated post here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/95124/stuck-trying-to-verify-a-smart-contract-through-hardhat